# Setting Vim key bindings for the MySQL client

Tags: vim, mysql, key-binding, readline

I add these following lines to `~/.inputrc` and now the Postgres client, psql, uses Vim keybindings.

```
set keymap vi
set editing-mode vi
```

However, this does not work for MySQL. I understand that MySQL no longer uses readline and instead uses editline. I've tried adding the above to `~/.editrc` but it still doesn't work.

How can I get Vim key bindings with MySQL?

I'm on Mac OS X 10.9.5 with MySQL 5.6.21 installed via Homebrew.

Comment: Did you try `$ man editline` and `$ man editrc`?

Comment: Yes, I did, but couldn't find anything. I found the answer after Googling last night. Thanks though :)

Comment: The answer is in `$ man editc`, ***not*** on Google.

Comment: Well, I found it on Google. Thanks for your feedback though, I'll bear it in mind.

Comment: Please answer your question below, using the **Answer your question** button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I needed `bind -v` in my `~/.editrc`. Now it works!